# React to a checkbox has changed its state in ObjectListView

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I have an ObjectListView (OLV) with 3 columns of checkboxes that enables and disables different calculations. Some react to the object in the OLV object but one checkbox column should also activate some recalculations outside the OLV.

I have looked in the cookbook, but I cant find any solution to my problem. The OLV does have CheckStateGetter and CheckStatePutter methods, but these are used during the change. I need to react after it has been changed. I also looked for a general purpose event like cellEdit, but a checkbox click is not an edit event.

Anyone know how to listen for checkbox changes after it has been done in ObjectListView?

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear to me what you are asking but maybe this helps.

```
objectListView1.SubItemChecking += delegate(object sender, SubItemCheckingEventArgs args) {
    // The event arguments contain information about current check state, new check state, the source column and so on...
};
```

> "one checkbox column should also activate some recalculations outside the OLV."

So check if the SubItemChecking source in the event arguments is the column of interest and you should get what you need.